# XXHDPI images look different on different devices with similar resolutions

Tags: android, xml, image, resolution

I have an image which I use as a background of a relative layout. The image is made keeping in mind the resolution of XXHDPI devices **(1080x1920)**. When I run the application in devices with physical navigation buttons like **Samsung S4** the image looks excellent, but the same image looks squished when I run the application in devices having on screen navigation buttons, like **Nexus 5**.

I am attaching the outputs:

**Image is fine in Samsung S4**:

[image]

**Image looks squished in Nexus 5**:

[image]

**The source code of the layout where this image is used**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.studystory.onboarding.screenOne">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/help_screen_one">





    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Why is the output different in 2 devices having similar resolution? What do I need to do in order to make the image look similar in both the devices?

Comment: "the resolution of XXHDPI devices (1080x1920)" -- density is not resolution. A 1920x1080 device can have any density, depending upon its physical screen size. Beyond that, your problem is probably tied to your layout resource or whatever you are using to assemble this UI.

Comment: @CommonsWare what do I need to do to fix the issue? I am not a designer and do not have much idea about the resolution and densities. If you can suggest the change, I will ask the designer to implement it in the same way.

Comment: You need to have scaling set to preserve aspect ratio and have images that can go out of the screen when the ratio is a bit off

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how to do that? Can it be done in code? Do I ask the designer to do anything for this?

Comment: Yes, it is done in layout code. The image control will have settings for it, don't remember them out cold.

Comment: "what do I need to do to fix the issue?" -- we have no way to really answer this. I pointed out that the problem "is probably tied to your layout resource or whatever you are using to assemble this UI". You have not posted any of that to your question, and so we cannot see it. Since we cannot see it, we cannot point out any possible problems with it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have included the xml code where I am trying to show the image in the question.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding your problem. I thought that your problem was the smiley face being squashed. That would not appear to be the background of a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: @kittu88 do not assign image to background of component. instead place it in an imagevew within the container. refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to use the image as the background of a screen as I am designing for On boarding screens.

Comment: `the resolution of XXHDPI devices (1080x1920)` There is no "xxhdpi resolution". **density** is a thing and **resolution** is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fixed this issue by modifying the layout. I used an imageview inside the layout to show the image.

**The example code**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.studystory.onboarding.screenFive">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/help_screen_five"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**android:scaleType="centerCrop"** did the trick.